# Is input sanitization required for flat file searches?

Tags: php

I have several static files. There is no database involved. These files are used for several different purposes. Code snippets, different international languages etc. How do I go about sanitizing input for a search query if the only thing I am doing is something like

```
$searchQuery = $_GET['q'];
$a = 'How are you?';
if (strpos($a, $searchQuery) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

which is recursively used on each file.

Is sanitization required in this case?

Comment: I think this is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the filenames are not provided by users, you should be fine. The function is only doing substring comparison, there's nothing to 'inject'.

Comment: By files, do you mean the file name to search in or file uploads? I would agree with the former - if someone specified `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`, you'd have problems - but I don't see anything with file uploads as long as they're handled cleanly.

Comment: File paths would be set by the script. Only the search term query. So strpos() is safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Injection happens when building a string/command in one language which is then parsed and interpreted by another; e.g. building a textual SQL query in PHP which is then *parsed and interpreted* as commands by an SQL database.

Nothing of that sort happens here, so you're fine.